# Querying related models that has foreign key to model in question (in one optimized query)

Tags: sql, django, database, model

I got the following models.

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class PhoneNumber(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Email(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class WebSite(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    url = models. URLField(max_length=200)
```

I want to query all the models from already obtained `Person` model since this should be my start point. I can do something like;

```py
person = Person.objects.get(id=1)
phones = PhoneNumber.objects.filter(person=person)
emails = Email.objects.filter(person=person)
website = WebSite.objects.filter(person=person)
# ...
```

However, the snippet above would hit the DB **four** times and I don't want that at all. Is there any way to make a query like the one below to hit the DB once (after person is already queried, which would be two in total at most)?

```py
query = Person.objects.get(id=1).getPhoneNumber(filters).getEmails(filters).getWebSites(filters)
```

As you know `prefetch_related` also results in hitting DB more than once. I don't wanna use `select_related` since I would need to use other models to get to `Person` model, which actually will have no difference when it comes to how many times it would hit to the DB since I got multiple models.

I am struggling to make a very performant query with the task above.

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE 1**

The following `prefetch_related` executes **four** queries. So every `models.Prefetch` I add, adds one more query. Is there anyway to improve that at all?

```py
    data = Person.objects.filter(id=1).prefetch_related(models.Prefetch('phonenumber_set',
                                                                         queryset=PhoneNumber.objects.filter(*filters),
                                                                         to_attr='phones'),
                                                          models.Prefetch('email_set',
                                                                          queryset=Email.objects.filter(*filters),
                                                                          to_attr='emails'),
                                                          models.Prefetch('website_set',
                                                                          queryset=WebSite.objects.filter(*filters),
                                                                          to_attr='website')
                                                         )
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've written the following raw query with my limited knowledge of DBs.

```
cursor.execute(SELECT * FROM "person_person" person
                  JOIN "person_phone" phone ON person.id = phone.person_id
                  JOIN "person_email" email ON person.id = email.person_id                  
                  WHERE person.id IS 1)
```

I mix the result with the following function provided by Django doc. Not ideal but with this way it hits the DB only once at least.

```py
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

It's hard to believe that Django doesn't allow this and you have to either use `prefetch_related` with extra cost or do reverse foreign key queries for each model.

Question still hangs, isn't there a way to do that with Django ORM? Optimized way of course?

Comment: `Person.objects.select_related('email', 'website', 'phonenumber', ...etc.).get(id=1)` should hit the DB only once. Then you can do `person.website`, `person.email`, `person.phonenumber`, etc. without additional db hits.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is where my confusion starts cause I am getting the error below when I do that.

`django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'email'. Choices are: (none)
`

Comment: That's weird. Did you by any chance missed any migrations? Is the relation working from the model instance, for example `person.email`?

Comment: Migrations are up-to-date. The following works. I have no idea what's wrong. Might it be a bug or something?
`person = models.Person.objects.get(id=1)
d = person.email_set.all()`

Comment: Ah didn't notice that the FK relation was outside person. In this case are you supposed to have multiple emails/websites/phone numbers for each person? If yes, then you will have to use `prefetch_related`. If not, then you might want to move the foreignkeys to `Person`

Comment: I see, thanks a lot for reply, much appreciated. I need the `Person` to have multiple entries in for each model thus the relationship. `prefetch_related` is expensive. So seriously, there is not other way to achieve that? I wonder about the big sites that uses django. They must have schemes like this one. I wonder how this should be handled with min query.

Comment: Expensive in what terms? `prefetch_related` should at most give you 2 db hits (if used properly)

Comment: Then clearly I did something wrong. Let me check the doc on `prefetch_related` and see why my query hits the DB a lot. Meanwhile, thanks a lot for your precious time. Much appreciated. I'll keep this post updated.

Comment: Hi @bdbd, 

I've updated my post with `prefetch`. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: It looks ok. So how are you using `data`? The main thing where prefetch can lose its purpose is how you use the results. Have a look at the first note on this topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: Specifically the part where it says: `Remember that, as always with QuerySets, any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query.`

Comment: Data is being passed to the template where the attributes used like `phones`, `website` etc. Nevertheless each prefetch hits the DB individually. Assuming it's due to `queryset` that need to be executed.

Comment: Yes, but all the queries should only be done at the point where you defined data. After that it shouldn't do anymore DB hits especially in the templates if used correctly.

Comment: Indeed, after that point there is no DB hit in the template. Though, even this one is a lot. So I am looking ways to reduce it. I am no DB programmer trying to the `JOIN` to achieve it (not sure I can, assuming it would be a feature in Django's ORM.

With that being said, as I said I wonder how big companies overcome this bottleneck.

Comment: Just updated my post above.